# Converting a number in exponential form to decimal form in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a very silly question, suppose if i have a number `1.70000043572e-05` how should I convert it into float i.e. `0.0000170000043572`.

Comment: `1.70000043572e-05` is a legal float just like `0.0000170000043572`. Are these "numbers" strings or floats?

Comment: these numbers are strings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to convert to a float and use str.format specifying the precision:

```
 In [41]: print "{:f}".format(float("1.70000043572e-05"))
 0.000017

# 16 digits 
In [38]: print "{:.16f}".format(float("1.70000043572e-05"))
0.0000170000043572
```

Just calling float would give `1.70000043572e-05`.

Using older style formatting:

```
In [45]: print( "%.16f" % float("1.70000043572e-05"))
0.0000170000043572
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are just inputting the number into your script python will understand that as a float.

If it is a string then use the builtin [`float`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) on it to do the conversion for example:

```
x = float("0.423423e4")
print "%.2f" % (x)
```

will output

```
4234.23
```

Comment: Can you remove IPython stuff... this can confuse the beginners.

Comment: just calling float would not actually work , that will still give the exponential format