# Pandas string was read in as string (object) but in numeric notation

Tags: python, pandas, format

I read in a csv file.

```
govselldata = pd.read_csv('govselldata.csv', dtype={'BUS_LOC_ID': str})
#or by this
#govselldata = pd.read_csv('govselldata.csv')
```

I have values in string format.

```
govselldata.dtypes
a                     int64
BUS_LOC_ID            object
```

But they are not like this '255048925478501030', but rather scientific like this 2.55048925478501e+17.

How do i convert it to '255048925478501030'?

Edit: Using float() did not work. This could be due to some white space.

```
govselldata['BUS_LOC'] = govselldata['BUS_LOC_ID'].map(lambda x: float(x)) 
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321336/converting-a-number-in-exponential-form-to-decimal-form-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a number in exponential form to decimal form in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321336/converting-a-number-in-exponential-form-to-decimal-form-in-python)

Comment: Using float() did not work. 
govselldata['BUS_LOC'] = govselldata['BUS_LOC_ID'].map(lambda x: float(x))

ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: Sounds like not BUS_LOC_ID is not all numbers.  Are there, Nans?