# convert number string with exponential sign in pandas

Tags: pandas

How to convert string number with E sign in pandas.

```
pd_data['c'] = pd_data['c'].astype('int64')
```

I got this error

**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '200E+05'**

Comment: Try choosing a float64 type

Comment: Do answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/28321336/9003184 help you?